# Unique Identifier (GitLab)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I need to know if there is something like an unique identifier for each file/folder on GitLab.

I know that if I change/add/delete a file inside a folder the "id" from that folder will change. I confirmed that with the projects/id/repository/tree GET method.
The only thing that seems to stay the same is Path.

I tough that to relate the folder(father) and the file(son) Git has to have something like an ID numeric or integer, but it don't seem like it. I'm right?

GET method from API:

projects/id/repository/tree

Exemple return

"id": "ac03bea27bb1eb7cf328258dg639c7f84340b355",
"name": "file",
"type": "tree",
"path": "file",
"mode": "040000"

When you change one file inside this folder the id changes.

Comment: All objects kept inside the objects DB (blobs/files, trees/directories, commits) have a unique ID. I don't know about the API, but you can get the ID by using things like: `git rev-parse HEAD`, `git rev-parse some-branch:path-to-file`, `git rev-parse some-branch:some-directory`, `git rev-parse some-branch^{tree}` and maaaaaaany more combinations.

Comment: @eftshift0 You are talking about github? I need it to be GitLab, and to use api. :(

Comment: git is not github

Comment: I need to use the api anyway... But thanks.